# Xubuntu, cron, не работает sleep

Tags: ubuntu, cron, xubuntu, crontab

Есть задача, выполнить скрипт через некоторое время после загрузки системы Xubuntu 16.04.
Я добавляю в крон команду:

```
@reboot sleep 30; bash /home/user/bin/xrdp.sh
```

Но sleep не срабатывает и скрипт запускается сразу, при запуске из командной строки вручную все хорошо работает и скрипт запускается после задержки, как надо.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: надо `@reboot sleep 30 && bash /home/user/bin/xrdp.sh` прописать

Comment: а можно еще вместо sleep использовать `at now + 1 minutes`, это если вдруг захотите долгое время ждать

Comment: Интересный момент, теперь если пишу `@reboot sleep 30 && bash /home/user/bin/xrdp.sh`, то скрипт не запускается вовсе, но если sleep поставить 15 или меньше, то как и раньше он просто запускается сразу, без паузы. Если вместо `sleep` использовать `at now + 1 minutes`, скрипт так же запускается сразу.

Comment: как вы определяете, что скрипт сразу запускается? откуда берете время boot и время запуска? приложите это к телу вопроса

Comment: В `syslog` я могу определить время когда крон вызывает команду. Но как определить точное время boot и время запуска после того как прошел `sleep` я, к сожалению не знаю. Определяю я это по загрузке рабочего стола))) просто при выставлении любого времени в `sleep`, программа по скрипту запускается еще до того как загрузились элементы рабочего стола.

Comment: пробовали 5 минут ставить, например?